Interpret p-value in A/B test results
I need to interpret the A/B test results. So, I have the control cohort named Baseline and also I have two other cohorts named NewFTUE and AppReopenFS.
The biggest problem from this AB test data is that NewFTUE has a p-value almost equal to 1 whereas AppReopenFS has a P-value much lower.
I can't understand 2 things:

As much as I understand, if the mean difference is larger as well as
standard deviation is smaller then the p-value should become
smaller, i.e. the null hypothesis should be easier to reject. But we can
see here that for a larger standard deviation and smaller mean difference the p-value is much-much smaller (0.187 vs 0.991)
The second thing that I can't understand is the 95% CI (As explained on the dashboard this is "The range of values that is 95% likely to contain the true difference in means."). So as you can see for NewFTUE the confidence interval for the difference in means is fully on the left side of 0. I.e. we are 95% confident that whatever sample we take (for the same sample size) we will get a worse results compared to the Baseline.

So why then the p-value for NewFTUE is 0.991 and is larger than 0.187 value for AppReopenFS?

EDIT: Adding the description of the p-value below: and here is the documentation page.


Something is off with these p-values. They are probably something else then we expect. What kind of software did you use and what does the manual say about this column in the table?

This is standard Google Analytics for mobile products @bernhard.

I would check the manual for Google Analytics, or else re-run this in R.

@PeterFlom I have screenshotted the description of the p-value and the documentation page.


That definition of p value is incorrect.  2. It's not the definition of p value that is the problem, but what Google Analytics did with your data. The table you posted makes little sense, so, either Analytics can't do AB testing (very unlikely) or you coded something wrong.  But questions about code are off topic here.


@PeterFlom You can't code something wrong, I guess, to get a non-sense p-value. You just send data, and it calculates the p-value. Even if you send wrong revenue data, it can't calculate a non-sense p-value, right? :)

It's a one sided p-value on the per user value. I don't see anything particularly weird. The definition are just the common misconceptions. My calculation in R (in cents): m <- -22;
s <- sqrt((84/sqrt(184))^2 + (112/sqrt(268))^2);
pnorm(m/s, lower.tail = F);

@LukasLohse maybe you can describe your answer in more detail as an answer to my questions. I have no idea what you wrote.

@Peter Could you state specifically what "makes little sense"?  I was puzzled by the table until I realized (a) these are one-sided (Student t) tests of the null hypothesis "the experimental mean is less than or equal to the baseline mean" and (b) the "Revenue per user" values have too little precision to reproduce the p-values; you should use the "Total revenue" for computations.  As far as I can tell, the main problem with this table concerns using a Normal (or Student t) distribution where the CV is huge.

@Lukas Although that's a good guess, the calculations are more consistent with a Welch t-test than a Normal approximation.  Having determined that, I discovered the documentation referenced by the OP supports this: "P-values are based on a one-tailed test, where the Variant value is greater than the Baseline value. Firebase uses an unequal variance t-test for continuous variables..."

@whuber  I thought of the one sided t test, but both of the treatments have lower means than the baseline. But I didn't think of it being a one sided test in the other direction. Good catch.   When I looked at the question, the documentation was not attached..

The Firebase website has some eccentric views on what a p-value is. "The p-value is the probability that the difference in performance between two variants could have occurred due to random chance." "P-value, which represents the probability that there is no true difference between the variant and baseline." For some reason, a lot of the popular A/B testing software programs  contain misinterpretations.

@whuber does that explain why the CIs are tighter? I find the results to fit very well to a normal approximation, if I use mu_diff = 0.125(see CI middle) in the 2nd and calculate just the 90%-CI. I would expect the t-distribution to not be differing much for n>100 and certainly not to narrow the CI.

@Lukas That's correct: I'm just reporting on what the software does.  The differences between the t-test and the Normal test in this instance are small, much smaller than the errors introduced by applying either of them to such skewed data!

In data analysis it is important to 'visualise' the data before drawing inferences. Graph the data (boxplot, scatter plot, or even just a bar plot with error bars) and inspect it and you notice that (i) there is too much variation relative to the number of points to make any firm inferences, and (ii) that the mean of one intervention is less than baseline and the other is larger.
Plot the confidence intervals for the means (baseline as well as the intervention values!) and you will see substantial overlaps as a result of the variation being large relative to the means and their differences. That is also a way to show that you need more information (i.e. data) before any firm conclusions can be reliably made.
Why are the p-values so different? Because, as @whuber pointed out in the comments, you appear to have one-tailed p-values both using the same tail but the mean differences are in opposite directions.

Thanks, I accept your answer but here I am making a note (yes, from ChatGPT) to make sure later readers could understand why one-tailed p-value should be close to 1 if the experimental mean value is lower than the baseline value. Please see my answer below.

could you please take a look at the justification of why p-value should be close to 1 for single-sided for this case when the experimental mean value is smaller then the baseline mean value?

@Narek I will not look at an answer generated by ChatGPT! That AI is not a reliable source of understanding of any technical or logical material. However, a quick search of this site will give you reliable and reasoned answers on most topics, and certainly on the tails of p-values.

Some of what the OP's found surprising has already been answered.

Google runs a single sided test; nothing wrong with it, since we want to see if the variant is better than the baseline
Google runs a Welch t-test; all good
Google compares the "revenu per user": ok. But the value given in the table are too rounded off to reproduce the p-values (e.g. the revenue per user for baseline is .67455, not .67...)

Now a few things to add though

While the OP's statement "if the mean difference is larger as well as standard deviation is smaller then the p-value should become smaller" is correct, it is missing one critical factor, the sample size. The 2nd variant had more users (202 vs. 184) than the 1st. A larger sample size will affect the p-value (because it reduces the width of the CI, by $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$.
Also, the 2nd variant has a higher mean than the baseline (not a smaller one, as the OP stated). The % difference is smaller, but the % difference for the 1st variant is negative (wrong sign, wrong direction for the test...)
So what the test proved is that the 1st variant is significantly worse than the baseline, while the 2nd variant is better, but not significantly so (at the "traditional" $\alpha=.05$ significance level).

And finally, a major issue with what Google displays. Google displays a CI of the difference of means (ok), and labels it "95% CI (Difference in means)".

While Google displays a double sided CI, the test (and the p-value) are for a single sided test. Misleading...
But in fact, it is a 90% double sided CI, not 95% as the heading says. Yes, there is a correspondance between a 2-sided 90% CI and a 1-sided 95% CI, but this mislabelling is just plain wrong.


People mentioned about that the nuance is connected with the one-sidedness of the null hypothesis testing, and I, as the one who asked this question, did not understand what does that mean so I have asked ChatGPT equation which explained me what is happening here. I am posting that answer here so that people can comment if this is wrong or people can benefit if this is right.


Hi, Narek, you can add further clarification by editing your question instead of using the answer field. Also, just for sanity check, chatgpt is not a reliable source for statistics.

@User1865345 that is why I ask for validation. And I thought it would be confusing to write an answer in the question. We have answer filed for answers, no? :)

I addressed your "I am posting that answer here so that people can comment if this is wrong or people can help benefit if this is right.", which I felt you were seeking affirmation whether you understood it correctly, and this, imo, should be in the question as update after getting the other answers. Pardon me if it is otherwise.

No problem, as I am 95% sure this is a good answer, I have posted here.

If you would like to understand one-sided tests, please search our site (there are several thousand hits!).
